# Is it possible to withdraw a German student visa application request?

Tags: germany, student-visa

I gave a student applicant visa to Germany Embassy in Kuwait, and it's be so long that I am thinking of cancelling and reapplying from my home country. If I were to do this, what would be the procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. You can do this... at least in Kuwait.

Alternatively you can ask them to keep processing on hold till you change your mind.

How to accomplish: Either call the embassy or mail them for further intractions.

Comment: The answer would be improved by including the reason(s) you know that "You can do this."

Comment: I did it myself

Comment: Very good, I'll remove my downvote. The Answer would be further improved for readers if you disclosed _how_ you accomplished this.