# Consequences of withdrawing a student national visa application

Tags: germany

few months ago, I applied for a German national visa, then later cancelled. Now, I took another appointment for the visa again next month, my question is would my previous visa request in any way affect my Visa in the future?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to withdraw a German student visa application request?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/26581/is-it-possible-to-withdraw-a-german-student-visa-application-request)

Comment: See [Valid D-Visa no residency permit appointment (Germany) - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/183555/95267) which explains how the **German National Visa** (type D) application works.

Comment: @MarkJohnson but how does either relate

Comment: Read the supplied answer and **think**. (Hint: it is **highly** likely that both applications will be handled by the same person).

Comment: Cancelling a visa application is probably a common occurrence, why do you think it might cause a problem with a subsequent application?

Comment: I did not know it is common @Traveller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asked about it on the second application. I submitted all the documents this time correctly and got my three months visa in two weeks.

So most probably no negative effects?